# My phone stuck on OS boot animation but I can use adb to connect to it, how to fix it without losing data?

Tags: custom-roms, boot-loop, boot, logging, treble

I have a Samsung s10e g9700 flashed with Corvus OS gsi (seems based on phh's gsi), which worked basically fine for almost a month. But when I flashed a modified system.img based on Corvus OS gsi, the phone stuck on OS boot animation (endless loop). Then I flashed back to the origin Corvus OS gsi , but the phone still  stuck on OS boot animation. I'm sure that I have only flashed system partition and the origin Corvus OS gsi can work. I don't know why my phone cannot boot. But I have found that adb can be used when my phone stuck on OS boot animation, so I have got some adb logcat:
[logcat1](https://pastebin.com/sJ9x5dUP) [logcat2](https://pastebin.com/YbgJv3i3) [logcat3](https://pastebin.com/mjDnBxtH)

I have not backup my userdata (there is no twrp for my device), and the data is FBE locked , so is there any ways to fix it without losing my data?

Comment: there is now way to break the bootloop in this case without losing data

Answer (score 0):

I once had an issue with something like that in my SM-J510FN. I flashed Bliss OS and because I didn't liked the OS, I decided to return back to Corvus. I had the issue that it got stuck at boot animation. I use TWRP, so I booted to recovery and then I went to wipe and selected Davilk, System, Cache and then re-flashed Corvus and it booted as normal. Hope this helps!